# How to set run as Administrator for Csharp Windows Form exe

Tags: c#, windows, forms, manifest, administrator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to force C# App to run as administrator on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-c-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7)

I had already done my codes and it's ready to Decode, however, i needed the pogramme to run as administrator. The question is how to make the program to enable RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR?

Comment: Right-Click the .exe and click Run as Administrator.

Answer (score 2):

Add a manifest file to project with [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) contents